# Axis Fault when connecting to HTTPS server

Tags: https, java-8, apache-axis, thick-client

We have an Eclipse RCP application acting as a thick client application and communicating with a Websphere server. We are in the process of upgrading from Eclipse Neon to Eclipse 2020. We are using jre11 and jdk12 to support the --Release function for a Java 1.8 compiler level. The application for the most part works, but we are encountering an issue with communication with the server. Our test server was recently upgraded to use https and tls 1.2. The client application attempts to use Axis2 to send a SOAP envelope to the server to retrieve some data. On the server side, we are able to see the envelope received, the request processed properly, and then attempt to return it to the client. This times out. On the client side, we get an error:

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).

It seems to dispose of the _operationClient, and make it unable to receive the response. I have had a hard time finding documentation on this, the codebase is very old and uses a lot of out of date functionality.

I think that it has something to do with modifying the transport receiver specified in the axis2 xml, but so far nothing I have used has worked. I don’t believe it to be a certificate error, I have added all of the server cert chains to cacerts, and the server is clearly able to complete the handshake, as it processes the request just fine. I can provide more information as needed. Everything I have seen online references BouncyCastle, but I have checked and it seems that our version of it is up to date. I have also attempted to set BC up as a security provider, but I have tried all the setups I have seen online do not fix the issue.